# Possible set of 4 integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, arithmetic

$A = [a,b,c,d]$ is a set of four integers. We pick two integers out of $A$ and add them. The following six sums are obtained $- 0,2,4,8,10,12$. Find the four integers in Set $A$?

All that I could figure out from this problem is that there has to be two numbers which will be $x$ and $-x$ then only we can get a sum of $0$. But I am still unable to solve this problem or devise a way to approach this problem.

Please help !

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Another observation, all sums are even which implies that all are the same parity... either all of the values are even or all of the values are odd.

Comment: if $x>0$ we note that $x$ must be the least positive integer in the list (as if $0<y<x$ then $y-x<0$)  Also there can only be one negative entry, clearly.  Hence if we order them we must have $-x<0<x<y<z$. AIt is easy to rule out $x=0$.  Indeed, it is easy to see that the integers are distinct.

Comment: Next, with having achieved six resulting sums, noting that $6=\binom{4}{2}$ that implies that the four values are distinct.

Comment: The sum of those six numbers must equal $3(a+b+c+d)$. So $a+b+c+d = 12$.

Comment: Pushing my comment a bit further, we easily see that $z+y=12$ and $z+x=10$ which imply that $y=x+2, z=10-x$  so now you are down to a single variable.  Easy to guess from here,  I see two different values of $x$ that work, giving two solutions.

Comment: For those who prefer to confirm via code: `for(a=-4;a<12;a++){for(b=a+1;b<12;b++){for(c=b+1;c<12;c++){for(d=c+1;d<12;d++){sums = [a+b,a+c,a+d,b+c,b+d,c+d];  sums=sums.sort();  if(sums[0]==0 && sums[1]==10 && sums[2]==12 && sums[3]==2 && sums[4]==4 && sums[5]==8){console.log(a + ', ' + b + ', ' + c + ', ' + d)}}}}}` yielded the same results as the answer below.  Not particularly optimized, but doesn't need to be.  The numbers are more than small enough.  (*was frustrated to be reminded that sort() did a stringy sort rather than numerical sort*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can let the four numbers in order be $a,b,c,d$.  (We know the four numbers are all different since they produce six different sums when they are added in pairs.)  The smallest sum (0) must be $a+b$, so $b=-a$.  The second smallest sum (2) can only be $a+c$, so $c=2-a$.  Finally, the largest sum (12) must be $c+d$, and $(2-a)+d=12$ simplifies to $d=a+10$.

The third smallest sum (4) could be either $a+d$ or $b+c$.  Let's solve both.

$a+(a+10)=4\\a=-3\\(a,b,c,d)=(-3,3,5,7)$

$(-a)+(2-a)=4\\a=-1\\(a,b,c,d)=(-1,1,3,9)$

It can easily be verified that both of these solutions generate the six pairwise sums, so there are two solutions.

Comment: Having written a quick and dirty script, my findings confirm the results.  I found exactly those two results as well.

Comment: @Matthew : I really liked the simplistic approach of your solution. Thanks for that ! But I did not get how you get to this : "The third smallest sum (4) could be either $a+d$ or $b+c$." Can you please explain this a little for me?

Comment: @Ganit One way would be to write out all 6 sums: $a+b < a+c < a+d,b+c < b+d < c+d$, so we can show the two smallest and two largest, but are unsure about the relative ordering of the middle two.